# C++ Pointer Error when assigning variable

Tags: c++, pointers

Trying to figure out this question.

First line is declaring the class, second line is creating a pointer object but doesn't have a variable type? is that the error? so the rest of the code cannot reference the info?

Thanks in advance.

```
//This doesn't work.  Why?

MyClass myObject1; //create original
*myObject1.x = 123;
MyClass myObject2;
myObject2 = myObject1;
printf("%d",*myObject2.x); //test the copy
myObject1.~MyClass(); //delete the original
printf("%d",*myObject2.x); //check the copy`
```

Comment: The first line is not "declaring a class", it is *defining a variable*. Everything else is even less correct.

Comment: Here's a rule of thumb. If you find yourself saying "this doesn't work", the question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. It is appropriate for your day's to-do list of things to research, but not for public consumption.

Comment: The second line is not declaring a pointer, but **dereferencing an object as a pointer.**  Need the declaration of `MyClass` in order to give a better answer.

Comment: This is from a C++ fundamentals class, I'm trying to understand what is causing the error. My I thought the pointer was an undeclared variable type and might be an issue but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You also have a problem in calling the destructor directly.  This doesn't delete the class.  Because of the way you have created the variable. That will happen when the variable goes out of scope, and then the destructor will be called automatically.  Bad things can happen if it gets called twice, as will happen with your code.